# How to fix errors when deploying akaunting to kubernetes cluster?

Tags: php, kubernetes, laravel

I try to deploy the web-app [akaunting](https://akauntuing.com) to a k8s cluster.

Therefore, I converted the given (and working!) [docker-compose script](https://github.com/akaunting/docker) using [kompose](https://kompose.io) to k8s yaml files.

When I try to apply these files (given `AKAUNTING_SETUP=true`), I get the following error; I have no clue how to fix it...

```
Call to a member function get() on null
Setting locale en-US
Creating database tables
Connecting to database akaunting@akaunting-db:3306
Creating company
[2021-11-22 13:14:32] production.ERROR: Call to a member function get() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function get() on null at /var/www/html/app/Abstracts/Commands/Module.php:59)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/overrides/akaunting/laravel-module/Commands/InstallCommand.php(50): App\\Abstracts\\Commands\\Module->createHistory('installed')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Akaunting\\Module\\Commands\\InstallCommand->handle()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Akaunting\\Module\\Commands\\InstallCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(186): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(263): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->call('module:install', Array, NULL)
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->call('module:install', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/database/seeds/Modules.php(32): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/database/seeds/Modules.php(20): Database\\Seeds\\Modules->create()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Database\\Seeds\\Modules->run()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(149): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(49): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->__invoke(Array)
#25 /var/www/html/database/seeds/Company.php(20): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->call('Database\\\\Seeds\\\\...')
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Database\\Seeds\\Company->run()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(149): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)
#32 /var/www/html/app/Console/Commands/CompanySeed.php(36): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->__invoke()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Console\\Commands\\CompanySeed->handle()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\\Console\\Commands\\CompanySeed), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(186): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(263): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->call('company:seed', Array, NULL)
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->call('company:seed', Array)
#48 /var/www/html/app/Jobs/Common/CreateCompany.php(50): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)
#49 /var/www/html/app/Jobs/Common/CreateCompany.php(27): App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany->callSeeds()
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(29): App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany->App\\Jobs\\Common\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection))
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(388): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->transaction(Object(Closure))
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->__call('transaction', Array)
#53 /var/www/html/app/Jobs/Common/CreateCompany.php(30): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('transaction', Array)
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany->handle()
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#56 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#57 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#58 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#60 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany))
#61 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany))
#62 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#63 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany), false)
#64 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(405): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchSync(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany), NULL)
#65 /var/www/html/app/Utilities/Installer.php(241): dispatch_sync(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany))
#66 /var/www/html/app/Console/Commands/Install.php(82): App\\Utilities\\Installer::createCompany('Schokoladensouf...', 'finance@schokol...', 'en-US')
#67 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Console\\Commands\\Install->handle()
#68 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#69 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#70 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#71 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#72 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#73 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#74 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#75 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#76 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\\Console\\Commands\\Install), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#77 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#78 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#79 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#80 /var/www/html/artisan(22): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#81 {main}
"}
In Module.php line 59:
Call to a member function get() on null
```

If you need more information to answer, feel free to ask.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi caylee welcome to SF. This is one of the very few times I've seen off-topic in the opposite direction, but your question is better served by asking over on https://StackOverflow.com/, since this seems like a coding error with the null dereference. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel I would usually agree w/ u in that point. The reason I asked here is that the same image works in a docker-compose environment

Comment: That doesn't make it on topic for a stack exchange dedicated for managing systems; it's still a laravel error about dereferencing a null var, something even the most casual debugging would help you troubleshoot